# Dependency grammar on ditransitive objects

Tags: dependency-grammar

[https://web.stanford.edu/~jurafsky/slp3/14.pdf](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Ejurafsky/slp3/14.pdf)
Page.23
[image]

I thought ditransitive verbs are head over direct objects and direct objects are head over indirect objects as in (b) System because I think literally only direct objects are directly dependent on verb and indirect objects are dependent on direct objects.

Why do indirect objects are directly dependent on ditransitive verbs according to (a) Reference?

Comment: Any system that analyses "the flight" as a DP are suspect. It's an NP, not a DP.

Comment: @BillJ They probly don't mean the same thing by _DP_ that you do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand the quoted figure the text around it is necessary. The *reference* parse (a) is the correct parse, the *system* parse (b) is generated by an (in this case unnamed) automatic system and contains two errors: The label on the arc from book to flight is wrong, and me is completely wrongly linked. So it is an illustration of potential errors in the parse. The caption also gives the two measures UAS and LAS for the correctness of the *system* parse.

Comment: Is the reference parse correct? It seems to have swapped the direct and indirect objects - compare to figure 14.5 in the linked document

Comment: Indeed, but for the sake of the argument it **should** be correct. Falls under "printing error", I guess.